# The equivalence of Artinian and Noetherinan for the modules of a semisimple ring

Tags: modules, ac.commutative-algebra

We know in a semisimple ring R, for every R-module, Noetherian is equivalent to Artinian, my question is:

If for every R-module M Noetherian is equivalent to Artinian, can we prove R is a semisimple ring?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let $R= k[\epsilon]/\epsilon^2$. Then module is Artinian if and only if it is Noetherian if and only if it is finite-dimensional. This is clear, since if a module is finite-dimensional there can't be an infinite ascending or descending sequence, and if it's infinite dimensional than $M/\epsilon$ is an infinite-dimensional vector space, so it has infinite ascending and descending chains.

But $R$ is obviously not semisimple.

Comment: The module $R$ is not semisimple, because the submodule generated by $\epsilon$ does not have a complement. The same is true for any ring with nilpotents.

Comment: In fact, Noetherian is equivalent to Artinian for $R$-modules if and only if $R$ is an Artinian ring.

Comment: $\mathbb{Z}_{p^2}$ with $p$ prime also work, and by the Wedderburn theorem and counting is easy to see that is not semisimple.